# Regex stop searching at specific string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get any character after a repeated specific pattern BUT I need to stop the search at a specific string.
For example:

```
anything anything anything:"pattern":"string" anything anything anything "pattern":"another_string" specific string anything anything anything
```

So I need to stop the regex at `specific string`

I have this regex:

```
/pattern":"(?<data>.+?(?="))/
```

So the result will be:

```
Match 1: data = **string**; 
Match 2: data = **another_string**
```

But it doesn't stop at *specific string*

I tried this regex but it doesn't work:

```
/pattern":"(?<data>.+?(?=")).+specific string/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use a lookahead to assert that "specific string" follows somewhere in the string.

```
/pattern":"(?<data>.+?)"(?=.+specific string)/si
```