# regex stop searching after '%' is found

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re
x=r'Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa%C3%B1a'
y=re.compile('[A-Za-z_](?!%)')
for i in y.findall(x):
    print(i,end='')
```

this is an example,i want the search to stop as soon as it finds % and print the previous words between them spaces in this example it should `Biblioteca Nacional de Espa`,i found this link [Regex stop searching at specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495583/regex-stop-searching-at-specific-string) but it was too complicated,any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex excluding specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352038/regex-excluding-specific-characters)

Comment: Your input  does not have spaces?

Comment: Why not just clip the part from the first `%`, and only then get the words? `x.split("%", 1)[0].split()`

Comment: Why not use `[^%]+` and capture the first element in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `[A-Za-z_](?!%)` matches a single character in your character set that is not followed by `%`. Due to which it will not print just `a` and `3` that appear just before `%` character and print rest every character in character set. But don't think you want that as your intended output is `Biblioteca Nacional de Espa`

You can use this regex,

```
(?<!%)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=.*%)
```

and find all matching inputs. Here is a sample python code,

```
import re
x=r'Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa%C3%B1a'
y=re.compile('(?<!%)([a-zA-Z]+)(?=.*%)')
tokens = y.findall(x)
print(' '.join(tokens))
```

It prints,

```
Biblioteca Nacional de Espa
```

In case you had a typo in your post and indeed wanted to capture `Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa`, then you just have to retain underscore (that I removed) in your character set and the regex becomes,

```
(?<!%)([a-zA-Z_]+)(?=.*%)
```

And your python code becomes,

```
import re
x=r'Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa%C3%B1a'
y=re.compile('(?<!%)([a-zA-Z_]+)(?=.*%)')
tokens = y.findall(x)
print(' '.join(tokens))
```

which outputs,

```
Biblioteca_Nacional_de_Espa
```